# How to use circle markers with Leaflet-Tilelayer-Geojson

Tags: leaflet

I am using [Leaflet-Tilelayer-Geojson](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/) to load points on a map and it is working very well. I want to use Leaflet circlemarkers instead of the default blue icons but I can't find any examples of how to do this. How do I use circlemarkers with Leaflet-Tilelayer-Geojson?

My code for loading the points so far is simple:

```
    var geojsonURL = 'MYURL/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson';
    var geojsonTileLayer = new L.TileLayer.GeoJSON(geojsonURL, {
               }, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

                layer.on('click', function(e) {
                $("#overlay").html('<img src="GIFURL"/>')
                .load("URL+feature.properties.url);  });


            }
       }
     );
    map.addLayer(geojsonTileLayer);
```

Thank you

Comment: I deleted my answer. I missed the TileLayer requirement. I guess you are talking about https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/

Comment: Thanks, I've added the link to the question to make it more explicit. Rgds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on the same thing for my web app. My first suggestion would be to use 
PointToLayer: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-options

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};
L.geoJson(someGeojsonFeature, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }
}).addTo(map);}
```

What I interpret this to mean, as explained at https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson, is that this would be the approximate result:

```
var geojsonURL = 'MYURL/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson';
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};
var geojsonTileLayer = new L.TileLayer.GeoJSON(geojsonURL, {
           }, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

            layer.on('click', function(e) {
            $("#overlay").html('<img src="GIFURL"/>')
            .load("URL+feature.properties.url);  });


        }
   }
 );
map.addLayer(geojsonTileLayer);
```